# Pydasm: Disassembling limited length executable shellcode

Tags: disassembly, python, disassemblers, shellcode

How to disassemble first 200 bytes of an executable code using [pydasm library](https://code.google.com/p/libdasm/) in Python?
I want to know how to set size of buffer to disassemble it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Slightly modified version from pydasm's [README.txt](https://code.google.com/p/libdasm/source/browse/trunk/pydasm/README.txt?r=2)

```
import pydasm
import binascii

# Open, and read 200 bytes out of the file,
# while converting buffer to hex string
with open('file.bin','r') as f:
    buffer = binascii.hexlify(f.read(200))


# Iterate through the buffer and disassemble 
offset = 0
while offset < len(buffer):
   i = pydasm.get_instruction(buffer[offset:], pydasm.MODE_32)
   print pydasm.get_instruction_string(i, pydasm.FORMAT_INTEL, 0)
   if not i:
     break
   offset += i.length
```

ADDED:

You also can play with `seek()` to go to certain position of the file, and then read from there. It is particular useful if you want to read shellcode embedded into some file and you know relative position. You will have to `open()` the file with "b" option for it to work. Consult [Python File Object Library Reference](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html) for details.